# Google Sheets Combining Is Between and AND operator Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

My programming knowledge is not great and I need some help. I am trying to get conditional formatting to highlight any cell in a column that contains values between 13-16 AND in a different column (same row) that contains values between 32-34. So, for example, if a cell in column U had "14" and in that row in column W had a "33" it would highlight the "14" cell.

After spending a ton of time researching, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(and(U1:U), ISBETWEEN(U1:U,13,16), ISBETWEEN (W1:W, 32, 34)))
```

My problem is that it highlights the cell in U but seems to be ignoring the upper limit of 16. So, it will correctly identify what I want it to, but it's also highlighting other things - like a U cell with a value of "18" with a W within the correct range.

I am at a total loss.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are usually not required in [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules. Try this rule for the range `U1:U`:

`=and( isbetween(U1, 13, 16), isbetween(W1, 32, 34) )`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't upvote because my account is too new but I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)